# Save provisional changes in custom controller

Tags: modules

I have added a button to the entry edit page, which runs a custom controller I user to copy data from field A into field B in a particular format. Here's a condensed version of that:

```
public function actionUpdateField(): Response {
  $entryId = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParam('entryId');
  $entry = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->one();
  $entry->setFieldValue('myField', $dataAsINeed);
  Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
  Craft::$app->getSession()->setSuccess('Field updated');
  return $this->redirect($entry->getCpEditUrl());
}
```

This is working fine, however, if I make a change to a field and create a provisional draft and then run my controller, I get 'Recent changes to the Current revision have been merged into this draft.'

Is there a way I can update my controller to fully save the entry, including any dirty fields?